# Theory MIPS instruction

Tags: mips

Knowing the program counter relative addressing, what is the problem with this code?

```
uno:    beq $t1, $t2, dopo1
……
dopo1:  add $t1, $t1, $t1
```

and how the assembler will rewrite the line to avoid the problem?

This question is on a test and I don't know how to answer. Actually I don't understand the question either.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be *any* problem there, unless the `dopo1` label is further away than 128kByte from `uno`.

Comment: Why 128KB?beq uses program counter relative addressing, not pseudodirect addressing

Comment: The branch has a 16 bit signed offset, allowing an address of PC +- 128kB to be targeted.

Comment: Oh yeah! Of course! So I think this is the possible trouble of this statement, Thanks!